# Fastest DB for audio data?

Tags: node.js, hash, binary, storage, nosql

What is the fastest free DB available between redis, mongodb and mysql (or other if justified) to use with nodejs for storing and querying audio data?

The audio will be stored in the wav format, and should not exceed 1 MB in size.
I expect the number of concurrent requests to around 50 per second.

My constraints are free DBs, and speed.

Is there any comparison between the different DBs on this?

Comment: Which DB are you using? MongoDB? MySQL? A custom one?

Comment: Storing a hash would not allow you to retrieve the data in a usable form.

Comment: I havent finalized any.... evaluating which would be a best fit that can handle binary data for quick comparison

Comment: Since the answer depend heavily on which DB you will use, you should evaluate then edit the question. As it stand, it is too broad.

Comment: Let me turn around the question and ask you if you had this issue what db would use...  redis, mongoDB, mysql... :)

Comment: That may be taken as opinion based, but should be okay if you precise what operation you expect to do on the binary data, if it is a hash or the whole data, and which DBs you are interested in comparing (and limiting that number.

Comment: Example: What is the fastest noSQL DB with node.js driver for storing, retrieving, and comparing binary files between Redis and MongoDB? Else it would either be flagged as tool recommendation, or opinion based

Comment: Some more informations about the data would also be welcomed in the question: "the expected size of the data is ~10MB, in mp3 format, and there should be around 100 concurrent request for comparison per seconds"

Comment: What is the fastest free DB available (redis, mongodb, mysql) to use with nodejs for storing, quering binary data(audio data). Audio data would be in wav format and not more than 1 MB size, number of concurrent requests expected 50 per second.

Comment: I have editted the question for you, I see it as fine as it is, but I can't guarantee that others won't close it down as tool recommendation. If you are unhappy with the edit, you can roll it back.

Comment: How are you going to query audio data? Just store it on Amazon S3?

Comment: The audio data is received from the user's browser to a nodejs server